# Regex Expression to recognize Routes or Paths

Tags: c#, .net, regex, routes

Im with issue with regex .net.
Id like make a exactly regex route.
Look the routes above as example.

```
/

/pessoas

/pessoas/vagas-disponiveis

/pessoas/vagas-disponiveis/foo

/pessoas/vagas-disponiveis/foo/bar/xpto
```

I need to make a regex that recognize exactly each one as unique match.

Using c#:

```
Regex.IsMatch("^\/pessoas\/vagas-disponveis\/(.+)$")
```

has conflict with:

```
/pessoas/vagas-disponiveis/foo
/pessoas/vagas-disponiveis/foo/bar/xpto
```

Complement...

```
**List one**
/
/pessoas
/pessoas/vagas-disponiveis
/pessoas/vagas-disponiveis/foo
/pessoas/vagas-disponiveis/foo/bar/xpto
```

**List two**

```
^/pessoas/vagas-disponiveis/(.+)$
^/pessoas/vagas-disponiveis/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)$
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have to use regex? [DirectoryInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) might be something you can use

Comment: Try [`@"^/(?:pessoas(?:/vagas-disponiveis(?:/.*)?)?)?"`](https://regex101.com/r/oP6vD0/1)

Answer (score 0):

Edited: Working from memory, I think this is what you're after:

```
Regex.IsMatch("^/pessoas/vagas-disponveis/([^/]+)$")
```

Comment: There is no point in escaping `/` symbols, they do not have any special meaning.